# VSCode completion with pygame works partially

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame, intellisense

Here is my piece of code :

```py
ball = image.load("./data/ball.png")
rect = ball.get_rect()
```

I have the intellisense completion when I type : `ball = pygame.image.` , it proposes `load`

But no completion when I type: `rect = ball.`

Whereas there is no problem with the NumPy package which is in the same location.

```py
a = numpy.ones((1, 1))
a.shape
```

I have completions for both lines.

Do you have the same behavior? Any ideas to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it cause an error when you attempt to run the code, regardless of `.` completion?

Comment: The code runs perfectly.
After some research.
It seems to be an issue witch is not solve:  https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1267

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't launch the Django process with `--nothreading --noreload` as specified in the [entry point part of those docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python#_example-configuring-the-entry-point-for-a-python-file). Try that to make sure you are running in a single thread on the server and that should fix the issue.